# MySQL MATCH AGAINST efficiency

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match-against

I have a small PHP articles system, and I'd like to add a Similar Articles list to each article (that would obviously be loaded very frequently).
I figured I should use MATCH AGAINST in order to populate the similar articles list, based on the title of articles.
The thing is, how would I go about actually implementing it?
Is performing the MATCH AGAINST query on each view of an article too intensive, or fine?
If it *is* too intensive, what are the alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: Do some reading first - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: 50 slides only: "Practical Full Text Search in MySQL" http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

Comment: @sanmai Well, so basically using MATCH AGAINST in EACH article page load, shouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find those articles that is similar to the current article's title, then try MATCH AGAINST and see how it performs. Running a query like this every time an article added (or title being modified) should not be a performance problem.

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('@newtitle');
```

However, if you want to find similar articles based on the whole text of the article, you may want to try calculate [similarity](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552) between article bodies and see if it gives better results then `MATCH AGAINST title`

In general, first I'd worry about actually finding the really similar articles, and then I may start worry about the performance. Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean, each time an article is added or edited, I should save the similar articles for that article? In that case, new articles that are similar to that articles would never be shown, and the same articles would always be shown for each article.

Comment: Well, I guess if article2 is newer then article1, then you are right in that article2 will not be assigned to article1 as similar. On the other hand, article1 will be assigned to article2 as similar. So what is the problem with that?

Comment: Well, a year from now, the old article would show old articles as similar. I guess I can live with that, I just prefer it would get updated at least every once in a while. Would running the MATCH AGAINST query on each article view (i.e. each time the similar articles list is to be created for the article) be too intensive?

Comment: @Lior, running MATCH AGAINST on each article on a regular basis (like in a background batch process every night) _could_ be too intensive, depending on the number of articles you have. But I still do not get why you would want to do that. Let's imagine you have a many_to_many relationship like this `create table similar_articles (art_id1 int, art_id2 int)`. Also suppose, that when you update or read this, you always check/update (which is actually delete and then insert) both sides (art_id1, art_id2). Hence it would be sufficient to run MATCH AGAINST only on new/updated articles, wouldn't it?

Comment: As I said, the only problem with this is that the same articles would always be shown once an article is created (or edited), and I would really prefer it would get updated). What are my options?

Comment: No, "not the same articles would  always be shown once an article is created (or edited)" Suppose article100 is created now, and MATCH AGAINST query returns article2 and article55. Now suppose that 1) article55 is edited and it is no more similar to article100 and 2) article101 is created and it is similar to article100. 1) when you edit an article, it is removed from the junction table from both sides (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) and MATCH AGAINST query is run against it again and the results are added to the junction table (these results will not contain article100)

Comment: 2) MATCH AGAINST query is run against article101 which will return article100 so this relation (101-100) will be added to the junction table

Comment: Hence at the end, you query your junction table for article100 (both sides) and 1) article55 will not be returned, but article101 will be returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3184/discussion-between-lior-and-bpgergo)